# Как сделать замену в xml файле выбранных в listbox элементов по индексу?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

Здравствуйте. Как сделать замену в xml файле выбранных в listbox элементов по индексу?

Пробовал сделать так для если выбрать все замена работает, если выбрать несколько разных в listBox показывает ошибку.

Допустим если выбираю в listBox США и Чехия то заменить в xml файле Россия Франция если другие элементы то другие.

listbox

США
Польша
Чехия

xml файл

```
<Root>
<Statya>
<TypeTermins>Россия</TypeTermins>
<TypeTermins>Германия</TypeTermins>
<TypeTermins>Франция</TypeTermins>
</Statya>
</Root>
```

<cite>

```
        List<XElement> hmlno = new List<XElement>();

        IEnumerable<XElement> list = oldXElement.XPathSelectElements("TypeTermins");

        System.Collections.ArrayList selectedd = new System.Collections.ArrayList(listBoxAlfa.SelectedItems);

        foreach (XElement elll in list)
        {
           List<XElement> listAgain = list.ToList();

           XElement[] arv = list.ToArray();

           hmlno.Add(elll);

           if (listBoxAlfa.Items.Count != 0)
           {
               if (listBoxAlfa.Items.Count == 1 && listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex == 0 && listBoxAlfa.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
               {
                 hmlno[0].Value = listBoxAlfa.SelectedItems[listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                 listAgain[0].Value = hmlno[0].Value;
                }
                else if (listBoxAlfa.Items.Count > 1 && listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex == 0 && listBoxAlfa.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
                {
                   hmlno[0].Value = listBoxAlfa.SelectedItems[listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                   listAgain[listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex].Value = hmlno[0].Value;
                }
                else if (listBoxAlfa.Items.Count > 1 && listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex == 1 && listBoxAlfa.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
                {
                   for (int i = 1; i < hmlno.Count; i++)
                   {
                      if (listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex == i)
               {
               hmlno[i].Value = selectedd[listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex - 1].ToString();
               listAgain[i].Value = hmlno[i].Value;
               }
                     }
                   }
  else if (listBoxAlfa.Items.Count > 1 && listBoxAlfa.Items.Count == listAgain.Count && listBoxAlfa.SelectedItems.Count == 1 && listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex >= 0) 
 {
  try
  {
  for (int i = 0; i < hmlno.Count; i++)
  {
    hmlno[i].Value = selectedd[listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    listAgain[listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex].Value = hmlno[i].Value;
  }
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
       {
          if (listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex == listBoxAlfa.Items.Count)
          {
          }
                     else if (listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex < listBoxAlfa.Items.Count)
                                                        {
                   for (int i = 0; i < hmlno.Count; i++)
                                                            {
                        if (listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex == i)
                                                                {
                  hmlno[i].Value = selectedd[0].ToString();
                  listAgain[listBoxAlfa.SelectedIndex].Value = hmlno[i].Value;
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
        else if (listBoxAlfa.Items.Count > 1 && listBoxAlfa.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
          {
          foreach (Object selectedItemm in selectedd)
           {
            for (int i = 1; i < hmlno.Count; i++)
              {
              for (int pl = 0; pl < arv.Length; pl++)
              {
              if (arv.Length > selectedd.Count)
              {
              if (pl == 1)
              {
              arv[pl - 1].Value = listBoxAlfa.SelectedItems[pl - 1].ToString();
              listAgain[pl - 1].Value = arv[pl - 1].Value;
              }
              else if (pl == 2)
              {
               arv[pl].Value = listBoxAlfa.SelectedItems[pl - 1].ToString();
               listAgain[pl].Value = arv[pl].Value;
                      }
                  }
                  else if (arv.Length <= selectedd.Count)
                  {
                  arv[pl].Value = listBoxAlfa.SelectedItems[pl].ToString();
                  listAgain[pl].Value = arv[pl].Value;
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
```

</cite>

Comment: Помойму , все должно быть намного проще, а по существу вряд ли кто будет разбираться в этом коде

Comment: Не такой и большой код, просто вид у него тут нечитаемый. @Demon, постарайтесь это исправить, тогда мы хоть сможем прочитать и понять его.

Comment: Как проще ведь я могу выбрать любое количество элементов и у элемента может быть любой selectedIndex? Допустим, если я выбираю в listbox 1 элемент и 3 то меняются со всем другие элементы или изменение не происходит.